# check if class is set in one div then remove class from another div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find if this div has class active, but I am not able to look for it by any other way except by data atribute, then if class active exists I need to remove class active from another div

to check for class existence:

```
<div class="shapes active" data-shape="other">

</div>
```

to remove class:

```
<div class="tips active">bla bla</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$('.shapes').click(function(){
    $('[data-shape="other"]').hasClass('active').find('.tips').removeClass('active');
});
```

nothing works so far, please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is  `tips` div placed inside `shapes` div?

Comment: Also `hasClass` returns a boolean not a jQuery object you can process further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way--

```
       $('.shapes').click(function(){
            if($('[data-shape="other"]').hasClass('active')){
                $("body").find('.tips').removeClass('active');
            }
        });
```

If tips class inside of shapes class then try this

```
$('.shapes').click(function(){
            if($('[data-shape="other"]').hasClass('active')){
                $(this).find('.tips').removeClass('active');
            }
        });
```

Both working.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have used the top one as tips is not inside shapes.

Comment: Welcome, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` to get the element which activated the event.

```
$('.shapes[data-shape="other"]').click(function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('active') )
        $('.tips').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check if the divs exist then execute the codes to prevent error if they don't.

```
if ( $( '.shapes, .tips' ).size() > 0 ) {
    $( '.shapes' ).click( function() {
        if ( $(this).hasClass( 'active' ) )
            $( '.tips' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    });
});
```